# WooCommerce: show all variations from different products ordered by attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I want to show all variations from multiple products and sort them by attribute (number).

I couldn't find a solution for that. I could show all products and display the variations per product. But I couldn't order the displayed products by attribute.

Is there any way to show all the variants?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code which may help you where only a PHP tricks is used.

```
$variations=array();
foreach($products as $product){
$product_s = wc_get_product( $product->ID );
    if ($product_s->product_type == 'variable') {
        $args = array(
            'post_parent' => $plan->ID,
            'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
            'numberposts' => -1,
        );
        $variants = $product_s->get_available_variations();
        foreach($variants as $variant){
            array_push($variations,$variant);
        }

    }
}
$variations=array_unique($variations);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($variations);
echo '</pre>';
```

Woo-commerce Method source : [get_available_variations()](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_product_variableget_available_variations/)

Thank you!

Comment: Edit: ah I see. It shows only the variations of a single product, right? I need a list of all variations from multiple products

Comment: Sorry! I think you have missed some things! get all product first then run this code where $products is referring all products.

Comment: use                                                                                                           
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product','post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1);                                                                                                       
$products = get_posts($args);

Comment: try argument only $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');

Comment: if I do that, the array is empty again